# Local spark connect to to remote hive and hadoop

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a single local spark node and want to connect to a remote hive, so I coppied `hive-site.xml` to `spark/conf` path. These are the main properties of this file:

```
<property>
   <name>hive.metastore.db.type</name>
   <value>DERBY</value>
   <description>
     Expects one of [derby, oracle, mysql, mssql, postgres].
     Type of database used by the metastore. Information schema &amp; JDBCStorageHandler 
     depend on it.
   </description>
 </property>
<property>
   <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
   <value>thrift://remote_host:9083</value>
   <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to 
  remote metastore.</description>
</property> 
<property>
   <name>spark.sql.warehouse.dir</name>
   <value>hdfs://remote_host:9000/user/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
   <value>hdfs://remote_host:9000/user/hive/warehouse</value>
   <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

Also,environment variables are set in `.bashrc` file:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/opt/spark/conf
```

Now, when running below code, I encounter the error:

```
  sc = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName(config.spark["name"]) \
    .master(config.spark["master"]) \
    .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", config.spark["maxToStringFields"]) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://remote_host:9000")\
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://remote_host:9000/user/hive/warehouse")\
    .config("spark.hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://remote_host:9083")\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()
   
    sc.sql("use database1")
    data_df = sc.sql("select * from table1")
    data_df.show()
```

This is the error:

```
  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.showString.
  : java.net.ConnectException: Call From my-pc/127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0:9000 failed on 
   connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details                   see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1413)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:776)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1676)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:437)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:420)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3625)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2695)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3616)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:763)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3614)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2695)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2902)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:300)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:337)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I don't understand where `0.0.0.0:9000` comes from.
How can I resolve this issue?

Much appreciated you help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the shown config, that's your hdfs namenode on port 9000, which would be configured in core-site.xml

Comment: Thanx, but in core-site.xml  the config is :

<property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://remote_host:9000</value>
    </property>

I also copied this file to local spark/conf but not still worked

Comment: I assume remote_host is not equal to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: exactly, it is the fixed ip address

Comment: like 192.168.1.100

Comment: Does the guide at http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused help?

Comment: Yes and still don't know what this part means: "Make sure the destination address in the exception isn't 0.0.0.0 -this means that you haven't actually configured the client with the real address for that service"

Comment: Right. That means the core-site.xml (or the config is manually set in the code) is still configured to use that address. If you remove `spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS`, anything change? Are you using local Spark master or yarn? If yarn, are the config files on that cluster all correct?

Comment: Cool thank, I removed spark.hadoop.fs.default.FS and nothing changed and still got error. I have a local spark master and not use yarn. Also note that when using beeline command of Spark, I can connect to remote hive